# Google benchmark : No rule to make Target***

Tags: c++, cmake

I tried to install google benchmark(https://github.com/google/benchmark) in my ubuntu machine by :
Remember I am using windows subsystem for linux.

```bash
# Check out the library.
$ git clone https://github.com/google/benchmark.git
# Go to the library root directory
$ cd benchmark
# Make a build directory to place the build output.
$ cmake -E make_directory "build"
# Generate build system files with cmake, and download any dependencies.
$ cmake -E chdir "build" cmake -DBENCHMARK_DOWNLOAD_DEPENDENCIES=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../
# or, starting with CMake 3.13, use a simpler form:
# cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B "build"
# Build the library.
$ cmake --build "build" --config Release
$ sudo cmake --build "build" --config Release --target install
```

and my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -lbenchmark -pthread")

project(proj)
find_package(benchmark REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(proj ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(proj benchmark::benchmark)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void BM_StringCreation(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state)
    std::string empty_string;
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCreation);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

and when I build it, I got this :

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/tmp/build/80754af9/snappy_1649923748780/_build_env/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so', needed by 'proj'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/proj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: I see typo.  This line: `cmake -E chdir "build" cmake -DBENCHMARK_DOWNLOAD_DEPENDENCIES=on ....` should be split to work properly.

Comment: Not reproduced, and also tried it on `ubuntu2004.exe` linux subsystem. BTW, `-lbenchmark -pthread` flags are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the `cmake -E <cmd>` stuff, try simply running cmake to configure the build instead. I don't think you're using most of those commands correctly, probably due to copy-pasting wrong (just guessing).

Try this, explanations are in the comments:

```bash
# Check out the library.
$ git clone https://github.com/google/benchmark.git
# Go to the library root directory
$ cd benchmark

# configure current source dir ('.') and binary dir 'build'
$ cmake . -B build -DBENCHMARK_DOWNLOAD_DEPENDENCIES=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

# build
$ cmake --build "build" --config Release
```

The commands in your post should be split across multiple lines, so for example, `cmake -E chdir build` should be `cmake -E` and *then* `chdir build` instead, etc.

Something probably went wrong when you were copy-pasting the commands. Either way, the version I posted above will (as far as I can see) do what you want.

Comment: I did exactly as you mentioned, still the same error

Comment: @dopller the same **exact** error? Something about `librt.so`?

Comment: yes! librt.so it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

The clue is in the error here:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/tmp/build/80754af9/snappy_1649923748780/_build_env/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so', needed by 'proj'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/proj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

It is trying to link against a library designed to be used with anaconda when it "should" be looking under `/usr/lib/` etc.

You can see exactly what it is trying to link against by looking in `CMakeFiles/proj.dir/link.txt` and you  will probably see a bunch of very important looking libraries in stupid places like `~/anacoda3/...`

You will most likely also see a link path to `.../anaconda3/.../benchmark.so.0.0` or similar which is not the one you just installed! which is probably in `/usr/local/lib/` (see `install_manifest.txt` in `/build/` of benchmark for where)

The issue is that when you install anaconda it, really rather obnoxiously for my tastes, installs launch scripts for itself in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (which causes your terminal to have `(base)` or `(other env)` at the beginning of each line), including placing itself at the beginning of your `$PATH`. It does this through bash script which looks like:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$('/home/richard/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/richard/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/richard/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/richard/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi

unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

So, CMake is looking in your path for places to link against, and very helpfully, anaconda does the double whammy of 1) mirroring key system libraries *AND* 2) suggesting its own path is the first place anywhere should look for them (since it puts itself at the front of `$PATH`).

Either way, remove the offending prefix to `$PATH`, or more generally, look in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and comment out the offending lines (and reboot etc.)

That worked for me.